# How to get a story associated with a request in Versionone API

Tags: versionone

I am trying to get all defects and stories that are associated with a request in VersionOne.
I am able to get a request which has a DEFECT associated with it.,in the following manner:

https:///Data/Request?sel=Request.ID.Number,Request.Status.Name,PrimaryWorkitems:Defect.ID.Number&where=ChangeDateUTC>='10-8-2014';Request.Source.Name="External";Request.Status.Name="Completed";Request.Status.Name!="Approved";Request.Status.Name!="";Request.Status.Name!="Reviewed";Request.Status.Name!="Accepted";Request.Category.Name="Defect";PrimaryWorkitems:Defect.Status.Name!="Accepted"

Now,I only change the Category to "Story",and I get a blank response. Not sure whether the Request.Category.Name ="Story" is correct or not.
Here is the REST call I am making:

https://www11.v1host.com/VentyxSandbox4/rest-1.oauth.v1/Data/Request?sel=Request.ID.Number,Request.Status.Name,PrimaryWorkitems:Story.ID.Number,PrimaryWorkitems:Story.Name&where=ChangeDateUTC>='10-8-2014';Request.Source.Name="External";Request.Status.Name="Completed";Request.Status.Name!="Approved";Request.Status.Name!="";Request.Status.Name!="Reviewed";Request.Status.Name!="Accepted";Request.Category.Name="Enhancement";PrimaryWorkitems:Story.Status.Name!="Accepted"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: never mind guys.got it! I jst queried directly on the story.Here is what the query will look like https://<server-name>/Data/Story?sel=Requests.ID.Number,Requests.Owner,Requests.Owner.NotifyViaEmail,Requests.Owner.Email&where=Requests[ChangeDateUTC%3E=%2710-8-2014%27;Source.Name=%22External%22;Status.Name=%22Completed%22];Status.Name!=%22Accepted%22 thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glad you found the answer that works for you.

To provide an alternative, here's how you can do this using YAML with the [query.v1](https://community.versionone.com/Developers/Developer-Library/Documentation/API/Endpoints/query.v1) endpoint:

```
from: Request
select:
  - Name
  - Number
  - Status.Name
  - from: PrimaryWorkitems
    select:
      - AssetType
      - Name
```

I left off the where clause, but this shows how you can use YAML syntax to shape the query with nested selects, effectively getting all Defects and Stories associated with Requests.